# Fullcalendar: in agendaDay (defaultView mode) display events of a specific day?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

Can Fullcalendar in agendaDay (defaultView mode) display events of a specific day ?
It seems that it only displays "Today's event" by default.

(using very old version v1.5.2)

I also tried:

- initialDate
- defaultDate
- year
- month
- date

Comment: You can still get the docs for v1 here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1#toc and assess your options. You'll notice that neither initialDate nor defaultDate exist in that version. You should have success with a combination of year, month and date options though. If you didn't get it to work, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of your issue showing the relevant code and data. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.